# Python While.Programa que lee numeros, hasta introducir 0.Una vez introducido 0, te dice el num mas grande introducido

Tags: python-3.x, while

Lo que tiene que hace el programa es el titulo(no se si es correcto a la hora de formular preguntas). Pues me hayo atascado aquí, no entiendo como hacerlo, he intentado guardar el valor en una variable auxiliar "numx" para luego compararlo con un if, con la segunda introduccion de valor en el while pero no hay manera. Por el momento tengo esto:

```
num=0
numx=0
lastbig=0
num=int(input("Dame num")) #pido un numero entero num
while num != 0: #si este numero no es 0 ejecuto el codigo de dentro
    numx=int(input("Dame numero")) #creo una variable numx para poder compararla con num
    if numx > num: #si numx es mas grande que num, guardalo en lastbig
        numx=lastbig
    else: #si num es mas grande que numx,guardalo en last big
        num=lastbig
#cuando quiera introduzco un 0 saldra del bucle
print (lastbig) #introduce el último numero comprobado mas grande en lastbig, lo printeamos.
```

Answer (score 4):

Veamos linea por linea lo que decis que hace y lo que hace realmente:

```
num=0
numx=0
lastbig=0
num=int(input("Dame num")) #pido un numero entero num
```

Hasta aca todo bien.

```
while num != 0: #si este numero no es 0 ejecuto el codigo de dentro
```

Claro, pero tene en cuenta que num nunca mas cambia.. nunca mas... porque nunca lo volves a pedir, o sea que de aca no sale mas

```
    numx=int(input("Dame numero")) #creo una variable numx para poder compararla con num
    if numx > num: #si numx es mas grande que num, guardalo en lastbig
        numx=lastbig
```

Y no.. si numex es mas grande que num, guarda lastbig dentro de numx.. tene en cuenta que se guarda lo que esta a la derecha del = en lo que esta a la izquierda del igual

```
    else: #si num es mas grande que numx,guardalo en last big
        num=lastbig
```

Mismo problema que antes

```
#cuando quiera introduzco un 0 saldra del bucle
```

Pero nunca pedis de vuelta el numero, o sea no va a salir.

```
print (lastbig) #introduce el último numero comprobado mas grande en lastbig, lo printeamos.
```

Si, si pasaras algo a lastbig, pero por los errores que vimos, siempre vale 0

Comment: Uf estoy agotado llevo casi 2 horas y no consigo verlo. Partimos de la base de que hacen falta dons inputs diferentes, en este caso num y numx? Almenos eso es así no?

Comment: o cambiar el numero que miras en el while ;) no se cual es la intencion de tu ejercicio

Comment: Programa que lee numeros, hasta introducir 0.Una vez introducido 0, te dice el num mas grande introducido

Comment: es un solo numero entonces.. no dos ;) vos estas pidiendo dos.. en realidad es uno con el anterior ingresado, hasta que ingresa 0..

Comment: [enlace] https://pasteboard.co/IEGPTXN.jpg [enlace] Me he tomado la libertad de pasarte el diseño del algoritmo, ya que me preocupa bastante no ver el error.

Comment: pero vos leiste la explicacion que te di? fui linea por linea explicandote que esta mal en cada linea...

Comment: si, de verás, y no consigo verlo.Voy a insistir por enésima vez.

Comment: Pasate por el [chat] y te explicamos

Answer (score 0):

```
mayor=0
num=int(input("intro num"))
while num != 0:
    if num > mayor:
        mayor=num
    num=int(input("intro num")) #se pone al final ya que además de pedir el nuevo num, tambien permitirá salir del bucle si es zero
print (mayor)
```

Comment: Isaac, enhorabuena por hallar la solución. Aunque es legal responderse a sí mismo, e incluso aceptar la respuesta, las respuestas que muestran sólo código sin explicaciones se consideran de baja calidad. ¿Por qué no añades la explicación de cómo funciona para que esta respuesta pueda ser útil a otros usuarios principiantes que hayan podido estar atascados como tú?

Comment: Así lo haré. Desconocía que fuera una conducta reprobable, un usuario me animo a que, si encontraba una solución , que la añadiera aunque fuera resuelta por mi. En cuanto tenga un momento lo hago. Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda, crucial.